# SQL Insert won't insert on all fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP generating an HTML form and I'm trying to write a script that will update the information in the database. For some reason it works on some of the fields and not others.

Code which won't work:

PHP-Form that users can change details within

```
echo"<form name='details'>";
echo"<p>Surname: <input type='text'id='surname' value='".$row['Surname']."'/></p>;
<p>Telephone: <input type='text'id='phone' value='".$row['Telephone']."'/></p>;
<p>Postcode: <input type='text' id='postcode' value='".$row['Postcode']."'/></p>;
<p>House/Flat Number: <input type='text' id='number' value='".$row['Number']."'/></p>";
```

AJAX - sends changes to server via querystring

```
    var sname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    var tel = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    var num = document.getElementById('number').value;  
    var pcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;

  var queryString = "?username=" + username +"&email="+email....";
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "url" + queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

PHP - execute update command

```
//connect to server
...
//get variables
$sname = $_GET['sname'];
$pcode = $_GET['pcode'];
$tel = $_GET['tel'];
$num=$_GET['num'];

//process update
$update ="UPDATE User SET Surname='$sname',Telephone='$tel',Number='$num',
Postcode='$pcode' WHERE Username='$username'";

//if query, display success
if(mysqli_query($update))
{
echo"success";
}
else
{
echo"error";
}
//else display error
```

The query executes fine, but the values aren't displaying within the database. My other variables (username, password etc) all update fine. All database fields are type VARCHAR(80).

EDIT: I do have the query being executed. This still results in the surname, postcode, number and telephone field not being updated.

Comment: First off, look up SQL injection and XSS. You've got some major security holes. Secondly, which fields aren't being updated? The ones that don't seem to be passed in/read from (`$username`, `$num`)? (edit: I think I miscounted the fields...)

Comment: Aware of security holes. Plan on going back to escape strings etc. Fields which won't update are num, tel, pcode and sname. There are other variables being passed in, but I've only included the ones that won't update to save copying too much code

Comment: is it your entire code? maybe you must have a mysql_query statement

Comment: I have the mysql_query. It executes and updates the other variables into the database but the ones I've included here aren't updated

Comment: The part you're missing here is where you actually execute the query. You say you're "aware of security holes" but this represents a massive misunderstanding of what [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) are. What you're doing is just plain wrong. You cannot write code like this as your first pass because, invariably, you *will* forget to fix it and then you *will* either waste a lot of time tracking down why Janice in accounting keeps crashing your app by typing in a surname of `O'Malley` or someone on the internet uses [a hacking tool](http://sqlmap.org/) to trash your site.

Comment: Spend thirty minutes to [learn how to use PDO effectively](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and be disciplined about using [SQL value placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you will never have these sorts of problems.

Comment: A more complete chunk of code would definitely help in figuring out what's wrong.  As it is, all we can do is suggest trouble shooting steps.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for the moment all the other issues with this code and approach (SQL injection issues, GET vs. POST issue, etc.), and dealing with the update not changing things as expected, there are a couple of things to check.

- Try outputing the update query in your logs and make sure that it actually looks like what your expecting.  It could be that the values you're meaning to push across the wire are not making it into the query or that.
- Verify that running the query by hand in an standalone SQL client (mysql, squirrel, etc...) Actually updates a record.  It's entirely possible that a valid update query may not match any records.  (Say the username value you're looking for does not match one that's in the database.
- Not knowing your infrastructure, I'd suggest some sanity checks: Are you actually pointing at the right database?  Do you have a your update wrapped in a transaction that's rolling back? etc ...

A few other tips:

- I would suggest looking at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), in particular how [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) work.  The kind of query you're building above is someone to run off with all your data or worse.  While not a panacea, prepared statements are a solid first step.
- Take a look at [Jquery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) functions.  In particular the [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.  It provides a simple interface for making ajax calls without having to construct special url strings.  Plus, switching to a POST will avoid your data showing up in webserver logs files.